# Foreach loop - 1-30 as alist and matching numbers to column in database on random (1,2,4) occurances

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I need help with a loop to echo 1-30 but after the 5th count list the numbers and match to a column in the database.  The numbers are random in the database such as 1,2,4 but I would like to match with the numbers ($x++):

```
    $x=1;
    foreach($forDB->results() as $f) {
    $x++;
    $id = $f->id;
    $name = $f->string;
     if($x<=5) {
        if($id == $x) {
            echo '<div class="list-matched">'.$x.' = '.$name.'</div>,';
        } elseif($id != $x) {
            echo '<div class="list">'.$x.'</div>,';
        }
        if($x == 5){
            echo ' | ';
        }
     }elseif($x<=15) {
        if($id != $x) {
            echo '<div class="list-matched">.$x.' = '.$name.'</div>,';
        }elseif($id != $x) {
            echo '<div class="list">'.$x.'</div>,';
        }
     }
    }
```

Now the results are good up to: 1 = stringone, 2 = stringtwo, 3, 4, 5 | 6, 7, 8, 9

but then stops at 9.. and it does not echo the 4th value from the database or any numbers that are jumping around the columns (ex. 1,2,4,6,9,13,15).. Seems to be getting 1 and 2 fine but when it skips one or more numbers it stops.  and tested by echo'ing the id after: if }elseif{$id != $x) { //echo x } echo $id;.. but it goes 1,2 and stops..  Please help!

Comment: Your problem is not very clear. Are you able to describe it more proper and descriptively?

Comment: What output exactly you want ?

Comment: Post Array of "$forDB->results()".

Comment: what are the column numbers?

Comment: I have 3 columns in mysql: tid auto_increment, id int which well match up with which ever number between 1-30, string varchar which will be assigned to the id for string data. I am trying to output numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23 , 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30...

Comment: But for each number that is out putted if it matches with the number in the list it echo's the string, ex if I had 1, 2, 4 assigned in the database column string and had id of 1,2,4 then it matches with the numbers that are echo'd in the loop and outputs the string: 1->stringone , 2 -> stringtwo , 3, 4->stringfour, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23 , 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30.. I have it output the correct id assign to the numbers in the loop but I would like all the numbers between the loop to display as well.